# How to display list of checkbox in rect-hook-form v7

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a code like this

```
const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([{
    id: 1,
    name: '1 - 10'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: '11 - 100'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: '101 - 1000'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: '>1000'
  }
  ]);

  const [productsPicked, setProductsPicked] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: '1 - 10'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: '11 - 100'
    }
  ]);
  

  const { control, register, handleSubmit, getValues, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    mode: 'onSubmit'
  });

  const complete = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(complete)}>
      {products.map((product, i) => (
        <Controller key={i} control={control} name="title"  render={({ field }) => (
          // i need to checkbox that picked checked by default, and i can update productsPicked here
        )} />
      ))}
    </form>
  )
}
```

All i need to do is create a list of checkbox products list. if product in list productsPicked, they default checked and i can update  can update productsPicked b,using react-hook-form v7. I am super new to react and doesn't know how to complete. Sorry for my bad english. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this into the map.

```
<div className="checkbox">
                          <label className="select_label">
                            <input
                              className="checkbox"
                              type="checkbox"
                            />
                         {product.name}
                          </label>
                        </div>
```

And this is the css code:

```
    .select_ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}    
.checkbox .select_label{
     margin: 1px;
}


.checkbox {
     display: flex;
}
.select_a{
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
}
```